# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Console Write Line

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to write a message to the console?  I'd like to write some debug data if it's possible.

Comment: What "console" are you using?  If SSMS, use print; if some form of advanced application with a database back-end, it would totally depend upon that application.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `PRINT` command emits a message that may be shown in a console depending on what tool you're using:

```
PRINT 'Hello, world!'
```

Not all clients necessarily show these messages though.

Comment: yup that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You mean `PRINT`?

For example:

`PRINT 'hello world'`

Answer (score 3):

For long-running operations, instead of PRINT, you might need to use the [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx) with [NOWAIT option workaround](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1660), since the messages display is cached.

Answer (score 2):

Higher overhead but you can log to the event logging system with [xp_logevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx).